# JavaScript <script> contents being commented out on conversion from JSF XHTML to HTML

Tags: javascript, jsf, xhtml

I've loaded a JavaScript script at the end of the <h:head> section of a JSF XHTML page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:fn="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="pageTitle">My Title</ui:insert>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/stylesheets/base.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" src="#{facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/javascript/myScript.js"></script>
</h:head>
```

I then add a call to a `myScript.js` function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     myFunction();
</script>
```

When the HTML generates, anything inside any `<script>` tag has been commented out:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myprogram/javascript/myScript.js"><!--

//--></script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--

        myFunction();
    
//--></script>
```

Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Some JSF impls indeed do that in order to support jurassic web browsers. Does it form a problem for you? How exactly? You might want to raise an issue ticket with them that it's no longer needed to attempt to support them (provided that they still do it in their latest version). By the way, the way how you authored the XHTML page is also jurassic. You might want to look up and catch up the HTML5 (introduced at 2008 already).